# Use textarea to populate Array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

(JQUERY) I'm trying to populate an array from within a textarea in my page, but somehow I can't get my head around the formatting that my array needs. How do I go around using "split" to populate this array form within my textarea?

This is for a local installation of Youtube External Subtitle (JQUERY Plugin)

Here you can see what each entry in my array needs to look like, but if I write this inside my textarea it doesn't respects this format.

```
{
"start": 10.28,
"end": 11.5,
"text": "PO: Master Shifu?"
},
```

And here's the code to save the textarea.

```
<textarea name="subtitulos" id="subtitulos" cols="30" rows="10" style="position:relative;z-index:10000"></textarea>

<script>
var subtitle = [];
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea#subtitulos');

function saveNames() {
subtitle = textarea.value.split(',');
var youtubeExternalSubtitle = new YoutubeExternalSubtitle.Subtitle(document.getElementById('ytplayer'), subtitle);
    }

function subtitles() {
console.log( subtitle );
}
</script>
```

Expected results: I wanted it to populate the array in the exact same way my array needs to be formating, so the subtitles can show up.

What ends up happening is I end up with some weird array that just splits either on \n or , (comma).

**UPDATE**
Some asked me what output I need. The output is a variable populated with the array from the textarea, but somehow it keeps telling me the variable I create is null (even when it prints it in the console!).

```
const str_obj = document.getElementById("subtitle").value;
const js_obj = str_obj;
console.log(js_obj);

var subtitle = [js_obj];
```

Results in: **TypeError: subtitle is null**

Comment: Can you specify what output you need.

Comment: Do you enter the object you provided in the textarea as input? (what should `subtitle` look like as an input?)

Comment: It looks like you should be using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn the input into an object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting the user input to create the object, you can use `JSON.parse()` instead to turn the textarea input string into an array of javascript objects.

```js
let all_objects = [];

const addObjToArray = function() {
  const str_objs = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  all_objects = JSON.parse(str_objs);
  
  console.log("The array: ", all_objects);
  console.log("The first object's start is: " +all_objects[0].start);
}
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt">
[{
  "start": 10.28,
  "end": 11.5,
  "text": "PO: Master Shifu?"
},
{
  "start": 10.30,
  "end": 11.15,
  "text": "Master Shifu: PO?"
},
{
  "start": 12.30,
  "end": 13.50,
  "text": "Tigress: Meow"
}]
</textarea>

<button onclick="addObjToArray()">Add obj to array</button>
```

You can use this idea to set the value of `subtitle` to be the object inputted in the textarea to a js object.

Comment: This is actually very close to what I am trying to do! 

I am experiencing a strange error though: I am trying to save "js_obj" into an Array, but it just keeps telling me that's wrong. See update.

Comment: @TiffanyAmber1 I've updated my answer. So now you can enter one object at a time and it will add those objects to the arary (`all_objects`). Is this what you wanted? Or, do you want to add all the objects in at once, click the button, and then have them go into an array, where each index is an individual object?

Comment: ahhh yes, I wanted to add all objects at once, so I can also edit those in case there are problems (which, will be!) Your example is very close, but if I want to edit one of the arrays I would have to go to the inspector ;( 

I'm working around your example to populate the array all at once and then have it update each time. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: @TiffanyAmber1 I've updated my answer, now you can enter an array in the textbox and you'll get an array as a result. If you want to change the array just edit it in the textbox and then click the button again for it to update

Answer (score 0):

This might hely you, I think you need to pass the string as JSON rather than just splitting it. The bonus is that you also get to keep all the information and access it easily.

The demo below lets you play around with the string formatting in the text-input and see how it works

---

## Demo

```js
$(document).on("click", "#test", function() {

  console.log("Parsing JSON");

  // Get text from field
  var inputText = $("#txt").val();

  // Parse JSON string into array of objects
  var objArray = JSON.parse(inputText);

  // Cycle through array of objects and print to 
  var l = objArray.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  
    // Print all the variables we are expecting - i.e. name, start, end
    console.log(objArray[i].text + " (" +
      objArray[i].start + "-" + objArray[i].end + ")");
      
  }

});
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txt">
[{
  "start": 10.28,
  "end": 11.5,
  "text": "PO: Master Shifu?"
}, {
  "start": 1.28,
  "end": 1.5,
  "text": "PO: Master Shifu? 2"
}]
</textarea>

<button id="test">Test</button>
```